# MouseMove event in WPF

Tags: wpf

In WPF when the MouseMove event is triggered, I want to check if the left mouse key is pressed, if it's pressed I want to do some calculation.

I have tried this:

```
private void Window_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        Calculate();
    }

 }
```

But when I left-click and hold and move the mouse around the screen the Calculate() only gets called one time (i.e when the mouse starts moving), after that no matter where I move the mouse the method does not get called.

I want the Calculate() method to get called repeatedly while the mouse is moving and while the left mouse key is pressed.

Comment: Are you sure it's not something else? A simple test for me shows MouseMove always being called, even if the left mouse button is pressed.

Comment: hmm ... strange - but can't you just set a flag (and MouseCapture?) on LButtonDown and release the flag (and capture) on LButtonUp? Seems somewhat cleaner to me and should work.

Comment: @Ray: yeah but maybe the e.LeftButton state is only set right after the button was pressed - this seems to be the problem here.

Comment: Thats true the MouseMove event is being called fine. But the Calculate method is only being called once, i want it to be called repeatedly while the mouse moves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple test for me shows this working:

```
private void MouseMoveEvent(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
       _vm.MoveCount++;
    }
}
```

A would suspect that your `Calculate` method is a synchronous method that's causing problems.

Try calling the method like below. This will start the calculate method in a new thread. Then the updating of the text box will happen in the original thread.

```
    private void WindowMouseMoveEvent(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker.DoWork += Calculate;
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted += 
                (o, args) => myTextBox.Text = (string)args.Result;
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }


    private void Calculate(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs args)
    {
        //do work
        args.Result = "my new value"
    }
```

Comment: The calculate method is about 50 lines, it has some if/else, a couple of Math.Abs and a Math.Atan2 calculation. At the end it has to update a simple TextBLock.Text value. I tried the calling method you recommended but it generates an exception "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it".

Comment: @xjay13 updated with method to call calculate in a new thread and update it in the original.

Answer (score 0):

I have verified it works. If I keep the mouse button down and move it over the window, the function gets called repeatedly as long as I move mouse over the window. May be your Calculate function takes a lot of time to execute and return back. So it is a long time before it gets called back again. In that case use multiple thread to called Calculate().

To test that this works I added a label to Window and put line label.Content = DateTime.Now.Ticks; instead of the calculate func here. It keeps updating the value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with element derived from Panel class, it fires mouse events only when it has Background property set.

Answer (score 0):

If applicable, the CRectTracker::Track function will capture the mouse until the user releases the left mouse button.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttwy7427.aspx